# SNS/PubSub notifications on a Python CLI Application?

Tags: python, push-notification, command-line-interface, amazon-sns, google-cloud-pubsub

I am developing a python application which will majorly be used as a command line interface. I want to push notifications from Amazon SNS or Google PubSub to the python application.

Is this possible?

If yes, what is the best solution to this?
If no, is there a workaround?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible for CLI applications

The workarounds are

1. Have a web api and register the endpoint with SNS. SNS will push notifications to the web API. From the web api somehow pass that to the CLI app, using either RPC calls or some other mechanism
2. Have the SNS push notifications to AWS SQS and then from your CLI poll the SQS